# Why does my laptop computer automatically wake up when asleep?

Tags: laptop

Anyone else has experienced such weired thing?

I used to switch my laptop asleep when I go to bed,but in less than 30 minutes it automatically wakes up,why?

Comment: Somehow I hear the "More info!" police coming... Better hurry and provide, well... more info! (OS, configuration, etc.)

Comment: What OS? Any attached peripherals? And it it waking up to then go straight in to hibernation? Is it connected to mains power (ie, could it be low battery)?

Comment: hehe, just as @m.capobianco predicited!

Comment: Obvious question: what happens when it wakes up.  Does it just sit at the Windows (or other) desktop?  Does a program run?  Does this happen regardless of what software is loaded?  Have you checked your calendar software for a regular alarm?

Answer (score 3):

Laptops can be configured to wake up by a number of events. This can range from Wake-on-lan (network activity), input devices etc..

To rule out which action is causing the wake up in your case, I'd first disconnect all cables (network cable, mouse, other USB devices...).
Then send it back to sleep and see if it still wakes up. If it doesn't, connect one by one again.

Answer (score 1):

If it only happens occasionally, it could be Windows 7 waking the computer out of standby to perform the automated updates (the default time is 03:00).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a ThinkPad, it might be caused by [Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). I've noticed that they would occasionally spontaneously resume, even when no Ethernet cable is connected. Try disabling Wake-on-LAN in the BIOS.